# plone 4.1 - plone.app.caching issue - unable to reduce http requests

Tags: python, caching, plone

Problem: I'd like to reduce the number of http request just by caching in browser some resources.
I've succesfully configured plone.app.caching in plone4.1 (without caching proxy), and no debug/develop mode (css, js, kss) is active.
I'm getting correct "X-Cache-Operation" headers in responses, but the number of http requests does not change (in firebug and instance logs I see status "200" for every resource, even for those with strongCaching option).

Here's a sample response for a png image with strongCaching option:

```
Server  Zope/(2.13.8, python 2.6.6, linux2) ZServer/1.1
Date    Tue, 25 Oct 2011 10:06:20 GMT
Content-Length  3676
X-Cache-Operation   plone.app.caching.strongCaching
Expires Tue, 01 Nov 2011 11:06:20 GMT
Last-Modified   Thu, 11 Aug 2011 15:13:14 GMT
Cache-Control   max-age=604800, proxy-revalidate, public
X-Cache-Rule    plone.resource
Content-Type    image/png
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug shows all resource responses, including those taken from the browser cache. The way to differentiate between the two is the colour of the entry; black means it required network access (e.g. the browser asked the server), gray is a cached response.

In other words, just because you see resources listed in Firebug, does not mean Firefox actually asked the server.

The `Cache-Control` and `Expires` otherwise look correct, your browser should be caching these results.